# Wordpress site sidebar overlaps content

Tags: wordpress, sidebar, overlapping

I am using the twentythirteen theme. The sidebar is not sitting in the right place, it is about 100px to the left and overlapping the content. The content is all lining up with the right space for the sidebar, but the sidebar is just misbehaving. The URL is http://gatorchristianlife.com/testing/ 
Any help would be appreciated. It looks like a simple fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.site-main .sidebar-container {width: 100%}
```

You'll want to get familiar with Chrome's developer tools or FireBug for Firefox--particularly the inspector.